# Help identifying bricks - non lego

Tags: set-identification, vintage

Please help me identify this non-lego brick set. I got this bricks set in the 1980's and had a lot of fun with them. But I cannot find what they are. I lost the box, but i remember there was a castle pictured on box.
Build quality is quite good and they still stick and fit well. Brick is exactly 1x1cm (black cube, white ones without connector ends) and there is also "plating" that can attach to brick and small window.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if these elements could be considered as "LEGO like bricks". Looks more like a (distant) variation of K'NEX instead.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's Fischertechnic (https://www.fischertechnik.de/en/). I'll see if any old catalogs are available.

Comment: my first thought was also Fischertechnik, but their old blocks are mostly gray

Comment: I don't think it is fishertechnik, the black brick lacks "pin" and center ridge is not made to lock the pin found on fishertechnik bricks. But maye it is an older set.

Comment: Definitely not K'NEX and also does not look like old Fishertechnic set. It may be a knockoff of sort, bought in former Yugoslavia in '80.